# what does mybatis really do when process a query like "select *"

Tags: java, sql, mybatis

I know mybatis will map the query result to a POJO accroding to the resultMap. I wonder, if I write a "select *" query, but the resultMap doesn't contain all the columns in the table, will mybatis rewrite the query to "select col1, col2,...", or still execute the original "select *" query? If I just want the results of a few columns, should I write "select col1, col2,..." in the first place, or mybatis will do the job for me?

Comment: `SELECT *` is antipattern.

Answer (score 0):

MyBatis is a lightweight persistence framework for Java and .NET. This blog entry addresses the Java side. MyBatis is an alternative positioned somewhere between plain JDBC and ORM frameworks (e.g. EclipseLink or Hibernate). MyBatis usually uses XML, but it also supports annotations since version 3.

@SELECT-Statement
The @Select annotation is very easy to use, if you want to use exactly one paramter. If you need more than one paramter, use the @Param annotation (which is described below at the update example).
You do not have to map the found information to a SimpleInformationEntity object, as you would have to do with a JDBC ResultSet. The magic of the framework does this for you.

final String GET_INFO =
“SELECT * FROM simple_information WHERE info_id = #{info_id}”;

@Select(GET_INFO)
public SimpleInformationEntity getSimpleInformationById(int info_id) throws Exception;

Comment: I know how to use @Select annotation, and yes, select * is antipattern. My problem is, if the table contains many columns, and I want to get most but not all of them, should I write "select col1, col2,...coln from table where ..." by myself, or mybatis will do some magic work based on my "resultMap" to avoid "select *"?

Comment: i dont know just chiill

Comment: Sorry, I thought you pushed the "down" button, my bad.

Comment: no bro if i want to push up or down then i need to must 15 reputiton

Comment: i have not pushed down...stack overflow not give me to permission of this beacuse my repution is less than 15

Answer (score 0):

Mybatis does not change the query based on the result map.

Basically the query is passed to jdbc directly with a preprocessing that is required to support dynamic sql generation, but nothing implicit only the processing that you programmed it do to.

Here's how the text of the query from the mapper file or annotation is processed:

1. `$` variables are substituted for their values
2. query parameters are substituted with `?` to meet jdbc syntax for parameters
3. dynamic sql elements like `if`, `foreach` etc are processed and corresponding fragments are generated